# Derivative of a vector-valued function devided by its absolute value.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, self-learning, cross-product

Let f(t) be a differential curve such that $f(t)\not=0$. Now, how to show that
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{f(t)}{||f(t)||}=\frac{f(t)\times (f'(t)\times f(t))}{||f(t)||^3}\tag{1}$$

My attempt:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{f(t)}{||f(t)||}\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{||f(t||}\right)*f(t)+\frac{1}{||f(t)||}*\frac{d}{dt}(f(t))$$

$$=-\frac{(||f(t||')*f(t)}{||f(t)||^2}+\frac{f'(t)}{||f(t)||}$$

Now where to go from here to get R.H.S of  (1)?

Comment: @user251257, Yes, You are correct.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{||f(t)||})=-\frac{||f(t)||'}{||f(t)||^2}$

Comment: hint: $\|f(t)\| = \sqrt{f(t)^T f(t)}$

Comment: @Paul, I got the correct answer.

Comment: If you got the right answer, where is the question?

Comment: @Paul, Here is the question for you. Would you give me a theoretical proof of $||T'(t)||=\frac{||f'(t)\times f''(t)||}{||f'(t)||^2}$ and  $B(t)=\frac{f'(t)\times f''(t)}{||f'(t)\times f''(t)||}?$